# Background gesture Recognizer not working for ios in xamarin.forms popup

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

For Xamarin.froms I have created a popup :

and I have used  ShowPopup to give background to popup so if I click outside poup poup will be closed ,its working fine in xamarin.android but for IOS gesture Rcognizer for Background view is not working if I have a popup on top of Background view

```
<StackLayout x:Name="ShowPopups" Padding="0" BackgroundColor="#99000000" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsVisible="{Binding ShowPopup}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
  <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OnClosePopupCommand}"  />
  </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
</StackLayout>
```

for Background popup in Xamarin.forms..Gesture Recoginizer working fine for background poup  for android but for IOS Command="{Binding OnClosePopupCommand} not getting called ..any suggestion to implement it

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to run this command on UI Thread :

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
 { 
   run your OnClosePopupCommand here
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for Solution

Answer (score -2):

You should try not using the Command binding for Xamarin.Forms.Gesture Recognizers, but rather the Tapped event handler. You should be able to make this slight tweak easily. Command has been deprecated and shouldn't be used going forward. Part of this is because gestures work differently between iOS and Android.

It is important to remember that Gestures are fundamentally handled differently between Android and iOS. Xamarin.Android implements gestures by utilizing the [IOnGestureListener](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Views.GestureDetector+IOnGestureListener/) to access the necessary override where Xamarin.iOS has a [UIGestureRecognizer](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIGestureRecognizer/) and UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to accomplish the similar.

Ignore Dany DaKur's answer because your code would be running on the UI-Thread. It is safe to assume that the first line of code coming from a UI control event handler (or Command) in Xamarin will be executed on the main UI-Thread. This is because the event handler is ALWAYS invoked from the main UI-Thread (otherwise how would the OS know the user clicked the gesture?).

I hope this helps!

Disclosure: I work for Xamarin/Microsoft

Comment: Thanks for Solution and I will try to implement it in  my app.

Comment: I'm curious. Where did you see Command has been deprecated ? As far as I know this is not true ! Command is just another way of handling gestures/event with the MVVM pattern.